# Does PCSX2 fully support Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Eater?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, pcsx2

Can I play *Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Eater* on the PCSX2 Playstation Emulator on a Windows OS?

I know that there are glitches but is it at least completable? I.e. playable to the end?

If it matters, my PC has:

- **Processor:** Intel 3.10 GHz i5
- **RAM:** 8GB
- **Graphics:** GTX 650 1 GB

Comment: Why has, are there any game breaking bugs while playing MGS3 on PCSX2, been downvoted without comment?

Comment: Is this about your PCs power or are you asking about whether or not PCSX2 "supports" MGS3, as in: Can you play through it without game-breaking bugs/glitches?

Comment: @MrLemon I am asking is MGS3 fully supported on PCSX2 ? Can I PLAY IT TILL THE END WITHOUT CRASHING ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The PCSX2 wiki has a list of games that work, but not any lists of *don't do this when you get here* that I could find. As in, for FFVIII on ePSXe, you should save state before all the mini-games because it likes to crash when loading those (a poor example, but you get my point). I would like the said list of ALL games that can be broken. That wiki has the final word on, *yea it works, no problems whatsoever*, huh?

Answer (score -2):

Based on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_2_technical_specifications) describing the PS2 technical specs, your system should be able to handle the game. The ram is 32MB and processor is 33MHz (not GHz) meaning your computer should be able to handle the game very smoothly, although depending on the emulator's efficiency your graphics card may not even be used to render the game.